# Null pointer Exception at Onclicklistener in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview

How to recover the problem of Null pointer exception in the place of menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
,
i have an imageview(menu) if i press on that another activity(about page) should get opened, but here on OnClick of imageview, i'm getting above error and app gets force close.
Here's the code

```
public class About extends Activity {
LinearLayout line1, line2;
ImageView menu;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
           menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        line1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (line2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE || line2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            line2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } 
        else { 
            line2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
        } 
          }
      });

          ImageView about = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.about);
          about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(About.this, About.class));
             }
              });
```

xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" 
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

      <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/menu" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_width="199dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ll1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >


  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/jobs"
    android:src="@drawable/about" />

  </LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@color/white" 
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

Comment: What line are you getting the NullPointerException on?

Comment: menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
at this line @drewmore4

Comment: Why you've not used `@Overrid` above `onClick(View v)` method ? this may be the issue

Comment: Can you show us how you define the menu variable?

Comment: 1st show the Declairation part of Activity wher you have instantiate the menu as Image there might be posibility that have called 1st and after that instantiate

Comment: if write override m getting this error ,The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method @QAMAR

Comment: First off, you need to add @Override on the onClick(View v) call (because you're overriding an inherited method here). Second, please show me where you initialized menu.

Comment: I hv edited the question and added the full code @drewmore4

Comment: @DDA: Please see my answer below. There is a difference between declaring the instance variable (which you have done) and actually initializing it. In this sense, you can look at the onCreate() method like a constructor in a regular java class. It's not enough to declare the variable, you have to initialize it as a variable of the actual object.

Comment: WHy dont you use this `menu=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);` any how you have used `ImageView about = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.about);` .YOu could have done an intial analysis before asking the question . If it is working for about and why not for menu ,

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, you have declared menu as an instance variable (at the top of your class), but you never instantiate it as a local variable. Add the line

```
menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu)
```

at the top of your onCreate() method, BEFORE you set the OnClickListener, and it will work.

There is a difference between declaring the instance variable (which you have done) and actually initializing it. In this sense, you can look at the onCreate() method like a constructor in a regular java class. It's not enough to declare the variable at the top of the class, you have to initialize it as a variable of the actual object.

This might sound trivial, but believe me it's not. When I was first learning java, before I wrapped my head around this concept, I spent many hours screaming at the screen over the same sorts of errors you're having now.

Comment: if i press on menu in that other acitivities m able to open those activities and even given the same code but null pointer exception error is only on this particular "About" imageview. and also if i give the above code m getting this error -Syntax error on token "menu", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token @drewmore4

Comment: Let me make sure I have this straight: You're getting the NullPointerException on the line menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()..., right? And if so, have you tried what I suggested yet? Is that where you're getting the VariableDeclaratorId message? Or is that somewhere else? Please post the line that's giving you that message. It means that you've called a variable class without giving it a name (for instance, if I called int = 0, without naming the int, I would get that error)...

Comment: menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu) ... i had made mistake by adding this code within onClick,, now its working,, thanks:) marked ur answer as correct, @drewmore4

Answer (score 3):

you are getting NullPointerException because you didn't have initialize imageview.please do it  first.

```
 ImageView menu=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);
```

write this line before you set onClick Listener to your image view and you are done.hope it will help.

Comment: i have initialised imageview as imageview menu; @Neurenor

Comment: oops: You haven't initialized menu, youve only declared it as an instance variable. @Neurenor's answer is almost correct, but you dont want to put the first ImageView in front of menu. Doing this will cause the instance variable to be shadowed, which you probably don't want. Simply add: menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu), and this code will work.

Answer (score 2):

You've not properly initialized the menu variable before setting listener you should

```
menu = (ImageView)findViewById(id.menu);
```

then write your listen line....

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the context of the activity which is running not the activity that you desire to run,the Problem is About.this , Replace it with the context of current Activity

```
startActivity(new Intent(About.this, About.class));
```

Comment: if i press on menu in that other acitivities m able to open those activities and even given the same code but null pointer exception error is only on this particular "About" imageview @Arash

Answer (score 0):

you have not Instantiate  menu 1st instantiate.

You are calling the same class with in the same activity change your following code as following

```
  startActivity(new Intent(About.this, About.class));
```

to

```
 startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewClass.class));
```

or

```
 startActivity(new Intent(CurrentClass.this, NewClass.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I found the xml id I'd used in findViewById() came from a different page layout than the one active at the time.

No warnings. Just need to make sure common buttons like Save have a good naming convention.